# how to call a function in a service dynamically in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, function, call

I want to invoke a function within a service based on the function name.
For example, passing a string as the function name and invoke it dynamically.
Can this be implemented using angular way?
The code in plunker is : http://plnkr.co/edit/A9RjFqcuc1FfuqmC4o02?p=preview

Main code is also listed below for your quick glance:

```js
    var app = angular.module('app', []);

    app.service("testService", [ function() {
        this.test = function(value){
            alert(value);
        };
    }])
    app.controller('testController', ['$scope', '$injector', '$parse', function($scope, $injector, $parse) {

        $scope.v = '123';
        $scope.click = function(param) {
            var service = $injector.get('testService');
//            service.test($scope.v);
            var expressionHandler = $parse('service.' + param + '($scope.v)');
//            expressionHandler($scope);
//            $scope.$apply(function() {expressionHandler($scope, $scope.users);});
//            $scope.$eval('service.test', {'value': $scope.value})
        };

    }]);
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="app">
<head>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div ng-controller="testController">
    <button type="button" ng-click="click('test')">click</button>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried out myself, the solution is: `service[param]($scope.v);` param is the function name to be invoked.